# how to set category name for a post

Tags: php, categories

how to set category name for post:
    this is my code ,this is not working ,why?

```
    $post_title = $vname; 
    $categ='category name';
$post_content = '[newpage link="'.$videos.'"]';  
    $new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 
      'post_category' => $categ,
      'post_content' => $post_content,
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_status' => 'publish',

    );
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post_category` parameter has to be an array of IDs (*int*).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Parameters

Try [`get_category_by_slug`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) to get the ID, then use it.

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'your-category' );
$new_post = array(
       ...
       'post_category' => array( $category->term_id )
    );
```

Alternatively, look into [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) or [`wp_set_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms), using the `$post_id` of the post you've just created.

If you need to add a category that is non-existent yet, create it using [`wp_create_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category).

Good luck.

Comment: your-category means?

Comment: @SANS780730 it's an example category slug.

Comment: not working.can u edit my code perfectly.

Comment: please can you edit my code correctly?

Comment: Are you serious? With 29% accepts, almost 30 questions and no answers, you expect me to "edit [your] code [to work] perfectly"!? Seriously?!.. You aren't putting ANY effort into your questions whatsoever, why should I or anybody else?

Comment: i am asking how to set category name for a post,give me correct full code  code from my code.

Comment: u see my full code:http://jsfiddle.net/bcZuN/1/

Answer (score -1):

Check this.. this may help you
'toys' => 'Kids' = 'slug' => 'Catregory Name',

So if you can add your Category name here, it will assign that specific category to all your posts. is this what you required.

Check this for reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories

http://wordpress-code-snippets.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-assing-category-to-post.html

```
Copy and Paste the Below code in you theme functions.php.

function auto_add_category ($post_id = 0) {
 if (!$post_id) return;
 $tag_categories = array ( //  add multiple items as shown 'Tag Name' => 'Categroy Name'
   'toys' => 'Kids',
   'apple' => 'Fruits',
 );
 $post_tags = get_the_tags($post_id);
 foreach ($post_tags as $tag) {
   if ($tag_categories[$tag->name] ) {
     $cat_id = get_cat_ID($tag_categories[$tag->name]);
     if ($cat_id) {
       $result =  wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tags = $cat_id, $taxonomy = 'category', $append = true );
     }
   }
   }
 }
 add_action('publish_post','auto_add_category');
  ?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? See [answer]